# Installing the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording

Tags: certificates

I got stuck in between while installing the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording in the Firefox browser.

I have followed the steps and successfully been able to generate the `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file but later on while installing I got the error message

> Failed to decode the file.  Either it is not in PKCS #12 format, has been corrupted, or the password you entered was incorrect.

when I entered the password as "password" without quotes [following the instructions as mentioned](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder).

Comment: Did you read the wiki too? https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/TestRecording210

Comment: I did not get the solution described. Though I already set up the path correctly,

Comment: i downloaded the new release and followed the steps mentioned on the official web portal and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link: [HTTP Proxy Server SSL Certificate TD5714504](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/HTTP-Proxy-Server-SSL-Certificate-td5714504.html).

Comment: We want self contained answers here, please include the link only for backup information.